# JsonPathRequestMatchers to ResultMatcher using MockMVC

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, jsonpath, mockmvc

I am testing a todo  controller using MockMVC:

```
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/toDos/")
                    .with(user("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN"))
                    .content("{ \"saved_date\": \"2010-01-01\"}")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                    .andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$.id").doesNotExist())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect( content().contentType("application/json"));
        }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.test.web.client.match.JsonPathRequestMatchers$5 cannot be cast to org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher
```

I want to delete the cast to (ResultMatcher) , but don't know how to create a ResultMatcher that tests the presence of Id. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use:

```
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath
```

... instead of:

```
org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath
```